# Javascript setTimeout misfires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a div upon an event. When a user clicks add to cart a small div should appear on the top of the screen stating that the task was successfully completed.

here is my code

```js
function display(){
  var target = document.getElementById('atc');
  var start = -35;
  target.style.top = $j(document).scrollTop() + 'px';
  var topVal = parseInt(target.style.top);
  var top = 0;
  var id = setInterval(show,0.5);
  function show(){
    if(top == 20)
    {
      clearInterval(id);

      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#atc').fadeOut().delay(2000);
        jQuery('#atc').css("top",start).show()
      },1000);
    }
    else
    {
        top = top + 2;
        target.style.top = (topVal + top) + 'px';

    }
  }
}
```

```css
.signifier
{
  position:absolute;
  top:-35px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color:#3e3e3e;
  padding:0.5em;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-to-cart" onclick = "display()">Add to cart</button>
<div class="signifier>
    <p>successfully completed</p>
</div>
```

although it works fine if the button is pressed once, but if the button is pressed repeatedly then the division stops showing up or shows up with some discrepency

Comment: Any reason you are not using jQuery to perform the animation?

Comment: You already use jQuery. Use jQuery methods instead.

Comment: Try jQuery. Why trying to get pro? When you can eazily get things done with lib!

Comment: I want the div to appear inside my view-port. As the div is placed absolutely I know no other way that to bring the div down in view port and then do the remaining animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> **Errors**
>
> > 1. `$j` is not jquery function .
> > 2. `atc` not id name try with full name of id `#add-to-cart`
> > 3. use `fadeIn` effect for setTimeout()

```js
function display(){
 var  target = document.getElementById('add-to-cart');
  var start = -35;
  target.style.top = $(document).scrollTop() + 'px';
  var topVal = parseInt(target.style.top);
  var top = 0;
  var id = setInterval(show,0.5);
  function show(){
   
    if(top == 20)
    {
      clearInterval(id);

      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#add-to-cart').fadeOut().delay(2000);
        jQuery('#add-to-cart').css("top",start).fadeIn()
      },1000);
    }
    else
    {
        top = top + 2;
        target.style.top = (topVal + top) + 'px';

    }
  }
}
```

```css
.signifier
{
  position:absolute;
  top:-35px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color:#3e3e3e;
  padding:0.5em;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-to-cart" onclick = "display()">Add to cart</button>
<div class="signifier">
    <p>successfully completed</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#atc').fadeOut().delay(2000);
        jQuery('#atc').css("top",start).show()
      },1000);
```

This timeout is not being reset or cleared. the delay and css change is not chained, so the css change + show is not affected by the delay...

You should really consider using jQuery.animate entirely without using setTimeout and setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this helpfull for you https://jsfiddle.net/wxdtw2sx/

```
<script>
$('#atc').hide();

$('#add-to-cart').click(function(){
$('#atc').show();
$('#atc').hide(3000);  
});
</script>
```